# User authentication in Firebase 3.0 javascript test code

Tags: javascript, testing, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to test drive some Firebase 3.0 client-side JavaScript.  I want to simulate a user logging in with email and password authentication and performing some database reads,writes and updates. I'm using Mocha/Chai to run/write my tests.

When I originally tried to initialise my Firebase connection in my tests using:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
var config = {
    apikey: "my-api-key",
    authdomain: "my-site.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseurl: "https://my-site.firebaseio.com",
    storagebucket: "my-site.appspot.com"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

I got the following error on the call to initializeApp():

> c:\Code\my-project\Web\node_modules\firebase\auth-node\auth.js:61
>
> ```
> throw new Error('Invalid service account provided');
> ```
>
> ^

I can understand that the test is running in the context of Node rather than the browser, so I've set up a service account and have successfully authenticated using that and performed a database update.

However what I really want to do is simulate a user logging in so that I can test my security configuration, but I can't find a way to do this.

Is there a way that I simulate user authentication from my javascript test code?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the node.js library only offers limited admin functionality (no sign in capability). Firebase team is working on adding a client side node.js library.

Comment: Thanks, any idea when it's likely to be available?

Comment: The Firebase team doesn't give timelines on unreleased features, but they are actively working on this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/SeXtoW28u6g/wf_w59pXAwAJ